# No rights to write on SMB mounted volume after updating on 10.6.3

Tags: centos, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard, apple

After updating on 10.6.3 I suddenly have no rights to write an mounted volumes via SMB. I had no problems before and nothing has changed regarding to rights on the Windows Server. I can read and copy files from the volume, but cannot copy a file to there. Mac OS says I would have no rights.
Any hint for that??

Server is CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

Some random dude accidentally stumbled upon a workaround:

http://splatdot.com/fixing-snow-leopard-10-6-3-samba-write-access/

Comment: I would just like to add that this is a terrible, terrible hack and removes (potentially important) functionality for other UNIX clients. Apple should burn and die for not addressing this well known issue that's existed since the introduction of Leopard in October 2007!